# What's the difference between betwwen 2 DB and 2 Schema

Tags: postgresql-9.2, tablespaces

My question is : what is the difference between the two next mode in PostgreSQL, for an production application.

- using two DB in the same SGBD (the same table-space and HDD)
- Or using two schema in the same DB

What about response time & performance ?

Answer (score 1):

By default, PostgreSQL's databases cannot see each other and you cannot query between them.

You can query between, or have foreign keys between PostgreSQL schemas.

If you want strong multi-tenant client segregation, use distinct databases.

Comment: What about response time & performance.

Comment: @bilelovitch measure it.  Also, don't add new questions to an already answered one.  Post a new one.

Comment: OK, for the next.